# Does a 2D Vector or 2x2 Matrix play any role in 2D Transformations?

Tags: 2d, matrix, vector

I'm having trouble trying to figure out if a vec2 or mat2 class are used at all in transformations for 2D rendering. Vec2, apart from representing UVs, AFAIK, is relatively pointless in regards to homogeneity.

What about 2x2 Matrix? I guess if we're hanging on to temp variables for shear, scale, and/or rotation it could make sense, but I'm feeling like I'll never use it.

It isn't much effort to implement, but I'd like to know if I'm missing something, or if Vec2 and Mat2 are largely useful for representing objects in 2D space.

I do know that a 3x2 or 2x3 matrix is a more data efficient* way to store the data for affine transformations-- does vec2 have any utility in these sort of cases?

- Or is this even true? Do alignment optimizations negate this advantage? Or is it only true for the data that we transfer into OpenGL?

Answer (score 4):

Of course they're useful.

A `vec2` is handy because you have absolutely no need to store the third component most of time.  It's only needed when actually doing affine transformations.  You can even have different `mul_point` and `mul_vector` operations with your `mat3x3` to avoid the need to even construct a `vec3` in a great many cases.  In 3D, we typically use `vec3` everywhere on then occasionally use it to construct an appropriate `vec4` where necessary, which is fairly rare.

For matrices, the same applies.  You have to deal with non-affine transformations all the time.  There's no good reason to use a `mat3x3` where a `mat2x2` will work.  Again, same in 3D, where there are plenty of places that don't bother with a full `mat4x4`.  It's a bit more useful in 3D since rotations are considerably more complex and you end up wanting to work with matrices for them more often than you might in 2D, but you still end up using them.  It's not always convenient or efficient to use a scalar rotation value in 2D given that it requires `sin`/`cos`/`tan` calls in places that a matrix would not.  You'll likely find that you often take your scalar rotation and convert it to a 2x2 matrix for computation of rotations where there simply is no need for translation.

Comment: Specifically talking about a 2D context- is it advantageous to even bother with the 2x2 matrix if we can represent shear/scale/rotation with decomposed 2d vectors?

I guess the question is more about what is optimal-- Is it better to build the matrix before sending it to the shader and store every transform independently, or to keep track of everything as the transform matrix directly?

Comment: I don't know exactly how a data member is passed to a shader but from what I do know sending position/scale/rotation as three separate objects or even as an array instead of a matrix might not be as efficient. But it's unlikely to be a bottleneck. I would recommend sending a transform matrix.

Comment: @ConnorHollis Hi connor! I actually just did some testing with sprite batching. I was using OpenGL and sent transform data via texture and built my transform matrices on the GPU instead of on the CPU. This turned out to be slightly faster than sending full transformation matrices. But like you said, this stuff is probably not going to bottleneck anything.

Comment: Well there you go! Testing is always the best way to find out which is preferable. Also remember that different configurations will have different results. So if you have a special machine you are using it could end up different but I would trust his results.

@RandyGaul I was also just checking out your source for SEL Randy, looks nice!

Comment: @user1195454: don't know about your specific use case, but I find that there's all kinds of math and such I have to do CPU-side and have to worry about a lot more than just raw GPU-bound graphics operations.  Physics, AI, etc.